# RxSwift wait for observable to complete, and return observable

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

When I use loadMovies function I get desired movies only after the ViewController has called function and disposed it, this function is inside API

```
func loadMovies() -> Observable<[Movie]> {
    let obsMovies = self.APICall(genrePath: Movies.action, structType: Movie.self)
    return Observable.create{ observer -> Disposable in
        obsMovies.subscribe(
            onNext: { element in 
                      observer.onNext(element)
                      print(element) 
           }
        )
        observer.onCompleted()
        return Disposables.create()
    }
}
```

In ViewController I call this function inside viewDidLoad

```
request.api.loadMovies()
    .debug()
    .subscribe(
        onNext:{ data in
            do {
                print(data)
            }
        },
        onError: { error in
            print(error)
        },
        onCompleted: {
            print("Completed")
        },
        onDisposed: {
            print("Disposed")
        }
    )
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

and get this output

```
ViewController.swift:55 (viewDidLoad()) -> subscribed
ViewController.swift:55 (viewDidLoad()) -> Event completed
Completed
Disposed
ViewController.swift:55 (viewDidLoad()) -> isDisposed

[MovieTest.Movie(name: "Black Panther", year: "2018", rating: "83")]
[MovieTest.Movie(name: "AVENGERS: ENDGAME", year: "2019", rating: "90")]
[MovieTest.Movie(name: "MISSION: IMPOSSIBLE -- FALLOUT", year: "2018", rating: "88")]...
```

I want to how to wait for function to fetch movies before being disposed.I want to display everything in tableView. I'm beginner at RxSwift, I believe there is better way to achieve this but as of right now I have no idea. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are a couple of problems to fix right away... `obsMovies.subscribe()` returns a disposable that you are ignoring. Since the closure it's embedded in needs to return a disposable, how about just returning the one that subscribe created instead of making a new one:

```
func loadMovies() -> Observable<[Movie]> {
    let obsMovies = self.APICall(genrePath: Movies.action, structType: Movie.self)
    return Observable.create{ observer -> Disposable in
        let disposable = obsMovies.subscribe(
            onNext: { element in
                observer.onNext(element)
                print(element)
            }
        )
        observer.onCompleted()
        return disposable
    }
}
```

Next, notice that `APICall(genrePath:structType:)` returns an `Observable<[Movie]>` so why not just return that rather than wrapping it in yet another Observable?

```
func loadMovies() -> Observable<[Movie]> {
    return self.APICall(genrePath: Movies.action, structType: Movie.self)
}
```

Wow, now I kind of wonder why `loadMovies()` exists at all...

So now that I have done the above, here's the output I see:

```
ViewController.swift:55 (viewDidLoad()) -> subscribed
ViewController.swift:55 (viewDidLoad()) -> Event next([MovieTest.Movie(name: "Black Panther", year: "2018", rating: "83"), MovieTest.Movie(name: "AVENGERS: ENDGAME", year: "2019", rating: "90"), MovieTest.Movie(name: "MISSION: IMPOSSIBLE -- FALLOUT", year: "2018", rating: "88")])
[MovieTest.Movie(name: "Black Panther", year: "2018", rating: "83"), MovieTest.Movie(name: "AVENGERS: ENDGAME", year: "2019", rating: "90"), MovieTest.Movie(name: "MISSION: IMPOSSIBLE -- FALLOUT", year: "2018", rating: "88")]
ViewController.swift:55 (viewDidLoad()) -> Event completed
Completed
Disposed
2021-04-11 20:05:08.356: Stuff.swift:55 (viewDidLoad()) -> isDisposed
```

Comment: Ohh I feel so stupid right now, it really makes sense. I spent last day trying to figure what was wrong I almost demolished my walls while banging my head . Thank you, well the loadMovies exists because I wanted to create multiple return types, on one occasion I want to fetch movies with `APICall(genrePath:structType:)` and on another I want to fetch Actors, my argument naming doesn't make sense right now, I just wanted to make this code work. THANKS

Comment: I put that "I wonder..." line in because generally, I'm not a fan of having a function that wraps one line of code. Why not just call that one line at the call site? It's something to think about.